# Click/Enter an element in dropdown with RSelenium

Tags: rselenium

I am navigating a website using RSelenium. I have to change the value in a dropdown menu before I can proceed. The dropdown menu let's the user choose the file format of a downloadable file, which can be downloaded pressing the "export" button. The dropdown menu contains the "Excel" and "csv" and is preset to Excel. I want to switch to csv.

Using my code, I was able to access the dropdown by clicking on it. I am also able to download the selected filetype via export button. But I don't know how to change the value in the dropdown menu.

```
#this is the dropdown
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', "#export_type")

#this clicks export
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css', "#tb-collapse-2 .btn-default")
webElem$clickElement()
```

I could probably click on "csv" by choosing the mouse position, but I want to learn a better way to do it.

I figured out that the dropdown has two possible option values (Excel and csv) by inspecting the dropdown code. I don't know how to "send" the option value to the element.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking at this, I found the (very simple) solution:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*[(@value = 'csv')]")
webElem$clickElement()
```

Notice that this using xpath instead of css. the @value is the place where you set the value. You can find that value via inspecting the page. Remember to click the element after it has been found in the dropdown.